# Designing and writing letters from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement to write a system to allow users to create letters from a selection of templates within asp.net.
The letters will vary from fixed format that cannot be edited, allowing the edit of some parts, through to completely free form.   After the letter is created there will then be a mail merge to add name, address and any other 'fields' embedded in the letter template before finally being rendered to pdf.

I have been looking at reporting components to assist in the creation/editing/rendering of the reports but I'm not certain if many of the features are overkill for what I am trying to achieve.

What sort of components are out there to assist with this type of application?

Answer (score 0):

I use **[Logixml](http://www.freereporting.com/)** for a while for and application like that. It's free, web based and **you could generate PDF out of it** using HTML based formatting.